# Google Map API in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, google-map

As we know that standard base component lightning-map has limited customizations, so I am planning to use a custom map using Google Maps API.

I know that we can import the JS file and use it as static resources, however, in this case, Google API is a dynamic URL "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap". How do we import this into LWC and use it?

I am trying to achieve something similar to this.

[image]

Comment: You can check my blog post http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2019/07/google-map-using-lwc.html?m=1

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? if yes can you please share?

Comment: Not yet, I am planning to use LeafLet, I will update once I find the solution.

Comment: @Ajay I'm also trying to display a google map with routing info in a custom LWC.  I can't get it to work and the out of box lighting-map component does not offer the extra's I need.  Are you having any luck using Leaflet?

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, Lightning Web Components require that an external library like this one be uploaded to Salesforce as a static resource. [The Content Security Policies in place demands it for security purposes.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.security_csp) This is likely why Salesforce collaborated with Google on the lightning map components that exist currently. That being said, there are some free, open-source map libraries out there that can get what you want (e.g. Leaflet, OpenLayers, Modest Maps) or you can embed a Visualforce page and use Google Maps with your custom code.

Comment: And on that page it states: "You can’t load JavaScript resources from a third-party site, even if it’s a CSP Trusted Site. To use a JavaScript library from a third-party site, add it to a static resource, and then add the static resource to your component. After the library is loaded from the static resource, you can use it as normal."

Comment: You're right! Got confused with how they worded things. [deleted previous comment to eliminate any confusion if someone else lands on this question]