# Validate approach (Googlemaps)

Tags: lightning-web-components

We have a requirement to create a custom UI using googlemaps.

lightning-map wont do what is needed from a customisation POV

Is there a way to load an external javascript in LWC if we turn off locker service etc.  I can't see any examples, I guess because originally you HAD to have all your JS hosted as static resources in Salesforce.  But I presume with LS off and scripting enabled, I can load external libraries.

Or should I just be doing this in Aura?

Comment: Check [Google Map API in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/290032/google-map-api-in-lwc) post.

Comment: So I've seen that and unfortunatly that doesnt move me forward. If I wanted to include externally hosted Javacript my understanding was that it was possible in Aura and LWC as long as the locker service was disabled.  For Aura that was using <37 and for LWC that was now available by disabling the Locker Service